# Is there anything known about interfacing between Synergy DBL and Python

Tags: python-3.x, synergy-dbl

I have written an application that queries a database and does some number crunching for a client. I was originally told i would be working with a SQL database, but have since learned it may be a Synergy DBL database. I am not familiar with this language at all and cannot find any open source information to dig into about it. Anyone know if perhaps their is some interface between python 3 and Synergy DBL?

I have attempted to connect to the database with pyodbc and was successful at connecting and creating a cursor but am unable to actually query anything. Here is my query function:

```
sql = ("SELECT * FROM Table")

def access_conn(sql):
    try:
        conn = pyodbc.connect('DSN=MyDSN;UID=MyUID;PWD=MyPWD ')
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute(sql)
        rows = cursor.fetchall()
        for row in rows:
            print(row)
        conn.close()
    except pyodbc.Error as e:
        print("Your query ran into this problem: {}".format(e))
```

I get the following error:

```
Cannot open 'Table', No privilege to this file or directory.
```

I have contacted the appropriate individual to ensure i have the right privileges to the data i am trying to access, and have confirmed in fact i do.
Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue was that i needed to add readonly=True as well as autocommit=True to my conn=pyodbc.